# Remote connect with a SQL Server alias without specifying the port?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I set up an alias in SQL Server Configuration Manager and it works on the local machine. However, if I try to connect to it from a remote machine, the connection only goes through if I explicitly set the port number via the comma (e.g. `FooServer\Apple,1433`).

Without specifying the port number I get this:

> Cannot connect to FooServer\Apple.
>
> ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:
>
> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified) (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: -1)

So I'm wondering if there's a way to be able to connect to the SQL Server instance with the Alias without having to explicitly set the port?

Answer (score 0):

You should create an alias for your server on the **remote** machine. Your client library cannot resolve the name now because it's unaware about what is this. Once you created the alias on the client machine, the alias will be resolved in ip,port and the connection should successed

Comment: By the way, it's a very strange thing in your post: FooServer\Apple,1433. If the port is really 1433 (default port) there is no need to specify neither the instance name nor the port; besides, when you do specify the port, the instance name is just IGNORED

Comment: That's why it's weird, it only works when the port is specified.

Comment: If your pc name is FooServer, it's enough to specify just this, FooServer